# Ember Data and Firebase Where is my Id

Tags: ember.js, firebase

I'm having trouble understanding how to update a record in an Ember.js that uses EmberFire and Firebase.

I have a small test application built to try to understand all of the CRUD functions. I can return a list of tasks that have been created, create a new task, and delete a task. But I cannot correctly update a record in a list.

When I look in the inspector, on my index page, I see that in the Ember debugger, under Data, it shows my model, and there is an Id field that contains the value that Firebase generated when a record was created on the server.

But when I console log the object that is getting passed to my Update Action in the route, there is no Id attribute. I think that is why I get an error of:

```
Error: no record was found at https://taskline.firebaseio.com/tasks/id
```

When hitting this piece of code:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
    return this.store.findAll('task');
    },

    actions: { 

    updateTask: function (model) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model)));
      this.store.findRecord('task', 'id').then(function(task){
        task.set( 'taskname', model.taskname);
        task.set( 'startdate', model.startdate);
        task.set( 'enddate',  model.enddate);
        task.set( 'banding',  model.banding);
        return task.save();
      });
    },
```

Ember Fire is supposed to handle the Id isn't it? But if it's not in my model object, how am I supposed to pass it to the find query?

Comment: Because .findRecord('task', 'id') is getting a string 'id' instead of real ID? 
 `this.store.findRecord('task', model.get('task.id'));`

Comment: yes. that was part of it. needed this.store.findRecord('task', model.id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you would like to update a model, one of the best option to pass the record back from the template/controller to the route action. In this case the record will be ready in your function param, so your updateTask method would look like this (only):

```
updateTask(record) {
  record.save();
}
```

The whole process:

**Firstly**, **in the Route handler** download all records, as you did in your example, and implement the action:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    this.store.findAll('task');
  },

  actions: {
    updateTask(task) {
      task.save();
    }
  },

});
```

**Secondly, in your template** list each task with input box. Maybe it could be a table. (I just have one field here `taskname`, but you could have more, of course.)

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Taskname</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each model as |task|}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{task.id}}</td>  
            <td>{{input value=task.taskname}}</td>
            <td><button {{action 'updateTask' task}}>Update</button>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you see, you are sending back the `task` record to the `updateTask` action in your route, so we are able to save it immediately. You can learn all these tricks in this free tutorial, which focuses on the Ember Way and uses Firebase: http://yoember.com

Comment: i did start your tutorial and got to lesson 5. then I segued to  https://medium.com/@jamesfuthey/a-gentle-introduction-to-ember-2-0-8ef1f378ee4#.3rqah9ect. Removing all of the extra content and simplifying the function to what you have above fixed it. BUT I still don't understand why my code didn't work. what was wrong with the function i had. what if I was only trying to update one attribute, not the whole record? What would the function look like then?

Comment: In your function, if you pass back the model itself: `this.store.findRecord('task', model.get('id')).then((task) => {
        task.set( 'taskname', model.get('taskname'));
        task.set( 'startdate', model.get('startdate'));
        task.set( 'enddate',  model.get('enddate'));
        task.set( 'banding',  model.get('banding'));
        return task.save();
      });`

Comment: So you have to use arrow function... however, in this case, you just download again that same record, what you already have in your frontend cache...

Comment: Ok. I think I understand now. I wasn't calling the id value correctly. One last question, the use of get. In the first line, using `this.store.findRecord('task', model.id)` will work. But in the set functions that notation fails. I have to use the model.get()...can you explain why the dot notation and get() are behaving differently. Aren't they both used to access a property of an object?

Comment: Probably the id has a special role, so you could have access directly, you can check it if you stop the code with debugger... however, better if you use get, because in an ember object a property is computed property, so it is recalculated based on changes or bindings...